# How to monitor apache tomcat running in windows via a zabbix agent?

Tags: performance, tomcat7, zabbix

We have a windows server that has zabbix agent installed. 
Recently we installed multiple apache tomcat 7 websites running in different ports and need to monitor the number of active threads, response time, etc. I need suggestions to retrieve the values.

Comment: You should start from the quickstart guide (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/quickstart/item) then move on to the JMX monitoring (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/tomcat) on Zabbix official website!
It might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked it already. I need help in collecting tomcat values via zabbix agent.